# Wordpress anchor menu active or inactive

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have an issue here. I am working on Wordpress-driven site (http://www.everaccountable.com/). Can someone help me on the menu?

The menu uses custom menu and the links there are only anchored and on the home page.

I would like to set the menus inactive (not highlighted) and make them active (highlighted) when scrolled or selected.

Just as exactly as this: http://www.maddim.com/demos/spark-r9/

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by custom menu? Are you using a custom walker to create the menu?

Comment: i'm using wordpress. links are custom instead of having the links provided by the pages created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.maddim.com/demos/spark-r9/ this is a one page site. But you site is not one page. You must right your code in one page. Then you can use http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Comment: I think , This is you are looking for http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-jQuery-Plugin-For-Scrolling-Web-Page-ScrollIt-js/demo/

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i'm looking for. i just want to put it on a custom jquery and custom css without modifying the wordpress backend.